# How to enable only particular card button on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have running Angular 9 and I want to enable button only when checkbox is clicked. I am using bootstrap cards and each card has its own checkbox and button. The problem I am facing is that whenever I click on any card checkbox, every button of the card gets enabled and vice versa. I want only particular card button to gets enabled or disabled.

**test.component.html**

```
<div class="col-3" *ngFor="let data of nominationData">
                    <form [formGroup]="nominationForm" (ngSubmit)="acceptNomination($event, data)">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <div class="title">{{data.contributor.name}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row" style="height: 190px;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <span class="nomination-title">Project Name: </span><div class="desc">{{data.projectName}}</div>
                                        <span class="nomination-title">Posted Date: </span><div class="desc">{{data.nominatedDateTime | date}}</div>
                                        <span class="nomination-title">Technology: </span>
                                        <div *ngFor="let data of data.technology; let i=index" class="tech">
                                            <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 10px;" [value]="data"
                                                (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
                                            <label for="chk" style="font-size: 15px;">{{data}}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12">
                                        <div class="buttons">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" [disabled]="!techStack.length">Accept</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="rejectNomination(data)">Reject</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    public search = '';
    private nominationSubscription: SubscriptionLike;
    nominationForm: FormGroup;
    isLoading = false;
    techStack: string[] = [];
    nominationData: Nomination;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private projectsService: ProjectsService) {
        this.nominationForm = this.fb.group({
            Technology: this.fb.array([], [Validators.required])
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getNominations();
    }

    getNominations() {
        this.isLoading = true;

        this.nominationSubscription = this.projectsService.getAllNominations().subscribe(
            {
                next: (nominations: Nomination) => {
                    this.nominationData = nominations;
                    this.isLoading = false;
                },
                error: (response) => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                }
            }
        );
    }

    onCheckboxChange(e) {
        const Technology: FormArray = this.nominationForm.get('Technology') as FormArray;

        if (e.target.checked) {
            Technology.push(new FormControl(e.target.value));
        } else {
            let i = 0;
            Technology.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
                if (item.value === e.target.value) {
                    Technology.removeAt(i);
                    return;
                }
                i++;
            });
        }
        this.techStack = Technology.value;
    }

    async rejectNomination(data) {
        const nomination: Nomination = {
            projectId: data.projectId,
            contributor: { name: data.contributor.name, emailId: data.contributor.emailId },
            // technology: data.technology,
            ProjectName: data.projectName
        };
        await this.projectsService.rejectNomination(nomination);
        this.getNominations();
    }

    async acceptNomination(event, data) {
        if (event.submitter.innerHTML === 'Accept') {
            const nominatedData = {
                ContributorMailId: data.contributor.emailId,
                ProjectId: data.projectId,
                UserType: 'Contributor',
                TechnologiesOpting: this.nominationForm.value.Technology
            };
            await this.projectsService.acceptNomination(nominatedData);
            this.getNominations();
        }
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.nominationSubscription) {
            this.nominationSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you have an array of `data` in `nominationData`. But the `techStack` variable is common to all elements of the array. You should have an array of `techStack` elements also.

```
// Initialize techStack to be an array of arrays
techStack: string[][] = [];
```

```
// In the getNominations function, once you receive the nomination data, insert empty arrays in techStack.
nominationData.forEach(_ => techStack.push([]))
```

```
// Modify the onCheckBoxChange function to take an index to indicate checkbox in which item in the list was clicked.
onCheckboxChange(e, index) {
 ...
 this.techStack[index] = Technology.value;
 ... 
}
```

```
// In the html, pass this index to the onCheckBoxChange function

<div class="col-3" *ngFor="let data of nominationData; let index=index">
 .....
 <input
    type="checkbox"
    style="margin-right: 10px;"
    [value]="data"
    (change)="onCheckboxChange($event, index)"
 />
 ....
 ....
 <button
    class="btn btn-success"
    type="submit"
    [disabled]="!techStack[index].length"
 >
  Accept
 </button>
 ..... 
</div>
```